# Symfony 4 - Compare two objects before persisting?

Tags: symfony, variables, session, compare

I've a Symfony 4 project.
In my controller, I've an action to edit an object in my database :

```
/**
     * Editer un groupe
     * 
     * @Route("/admin/validation/{id}", name="admin_validation_edit")
     *
     * @param GroupeValidateurs $groupeValidateurs
     * @return void
     */
    public function edit(GroupeValidateurs $groupeValidateurs, Request $request)
    {


        $form = $this->createForm(GroupeValidateursType::class, $groupeValidateurs);
        $form->handleRequest($request);


        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
          //persist and flush in database
    }
```

But when my form is submitted, I would like to compare my old and my new object, to make some actions.

For that, I used a session vairable :

```
$session = $this->get('session');

        if (!$session->has('groupe')) {
            $session->set('groupe', $groupeValidateurs);
        }
```

And I remove it when the form is submitted and valid.

It works, but it's not correct, because, if I go on an edit page with some groupeValidateur, and just after, I go on another edit page with another groupeValidateur, My session variable will contains my previous groupeValidateur.

Which solution can I use please ?

Comment: the form component may always edit the object it is given according to the submission by the user (or data given via submit). a session is a very bad storage for anything except the session itself. that being said, it's unclear how you want to "compare" the old and new object and what those actions might be and when they are executed...

Comment: I just want to take the User collection in my object before and after editing to apply some modifications if some users are removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before `$form->handleRequest($request)` your object `$groupeValidateurs` is still the original.

If you want to keep some information there are several options, amongst those the very easy and straightforward:

#### handle outside object and outside the form component:

if I understood you correctly, you only want to prevent certain users to be added/removed. Since I don't know your entity, I will assume, that your object has a method `getUsers()`, that returns the current users.

```
$oldUsers = $groupeValidateurs->getUsers(); // I assume $oldUsers is an ARRAY***
$form = $this->createForm(...)
//...
if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $newUsers = $groupeValidateurs->getUsers();
    // do whatever ...
}
```

***) if this is a OneToMany or ManyToMany relation, make sure to return the array instead of the collection:

```
public function getUsers() { 
    return $this->users instanceof \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
           ? $this->users->toArray() 
           : $this->users; 
}
```

if you manage to keep `$this->users` as a `Collection` always, you can just `return $this->users->toArray();`

#### other options:

- add event listeners to the form, that capture the data before edits come in, add this to a constraint that gets an additional list of users to prevent from being added/removed
- IF there is a property on the user which makes it clear, the user shall not be removed ever, you can bake this into your add/removeUser function:

  ```
  function removeUser($user) { 
      if($user->isAdmin()) { 
          return; 
      }     
      $this->users->removeElement($user); // I assume users to be a doctrine Collection
  }
  function setUsers($users) {
      foreach($this->users as $user) {
          if($user->isAdmin() && !in_array($users)) {
              $users[] = $user; // add user;
          }
      }
      $this->users = $users;
  }
  ```

  note: depending on your form, you might have to set [by_reference](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#by-reference) to false. which imho is not a real problem if a) your `getUsers()` returns the array instead of the collection (how it should be) or b) if you implement `addUser`/`removeUser`.
  also, this approach has the obvious caveat, that nobody can remove that user without removing the admin privilege, so maybe this is overkill ;o)
- setup a doctrine event listener for updates on your entity type that checks for removed users and re-add them accordingly. for this to work, you either have to check the changesets somehow (this is quite the overkill probably)
- upon changing the users of an object, store the old version (if add/remove implementation, take care not to overwrite the backup) of user list
- implement `clone` on your entity properly and actually produce a copy of your object before getting it changed (by handleRequest). compare at will.
- get the original entity as Andrea Manzi described and compare with that.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! :D

Answer (score 1):

In edit "action" try using:

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $currentdata = $form->getData();
    /**/
}
```

to get current data submitted

Or write an "update" action like this:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
    /* @var $em EntityManager */
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository(Entity::class)->find($id); //your GroupeValidateurs entity class

    $form = $this->createForm(GroupeValidateursType::class, $groupeValidateurs);
    $form->handleRequest($request);


    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
      //persist and flush in database
        $currentdata = $form->getData();
        $beforedata = $em->getUnitOfWork()->getOriginalEntityData($entity);
        /*....*/
    }
```

Comment: Okay but if I want the previous data, before submitting ?

Comment: I like your approach accessing the UnitOfWork, that's fancy ;o)

Comment: @Jakumi i use it in our little project to save logs of record change :-) https://github.com/ComuneFI/BiCoreBundle/blob/ebb45b202e521cb5f926bbcab529c3a108897998/src/Cdf/BiCoreBundle/Controller/FiCoreCrudControllerTrait.php#L177

Comment: @AndreaManzi huh, I would have probably used doctrine's onFlush event for that (as to be agnostic to where this change happens). on the other hand ... you're using a trait to inject that logic into every entity controller. okay, it's starting to get off-topic. sry.

Answer (score 0):

Clone object to $cloneGroupeValidateurs. Set entity to form. Next submitting your form and compare with previously cloned variable.